# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes on bootup(nvidia graphic card issue which a lot of people have faced apparently)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, live-usb, nvidia-geforce

So I've got the Dell G3 3590 i7+Nvidia GTX 1660Ti Max Q set up. I've win10 as my primary OS but I wanna dual boot with Ubuntu.
I wanted to try the "try Ubuntu" option using the live usb thing. However, my laptop would freeze even before I could select the "try Ubuntu" button.
I tried inputting `nomodeset` in grub, and that worked...but I learned(I might have misunderstood) it basically disables the graphic card drivers and doesn't use it. Plus I've to keep inputting `nomodeset` every time I bootup which would be annoying honestly(Plus I want to use my graphic card for Data science stuff using the python cudf module).
I also tried the thing where I go to driver updates and under additional drivers, select the Nvidia proprietary driver. After I rebooted, my laptop froze again, although I could get beyond the try ubuntu option without `nomodeset` this time.(keep in mind I've done everything on the live usb only and have not actually installed Linux on my laptop)
I've basically followed the step 1, 2 and the alternate step 3 on [this site](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/)

Does anyone know a fix to this? It's apparently not a Dell G3 specific thing, a lot of people have faced this issue, especially the ones with Nvidia graphic cards. Please can anyone help?

Edit: So after first using `nomodeset` I used the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` in the terminal and tried to reboot the live usb. Without using `nomodeset`, it'd get stuck at the Dell+Ubuntu logo screen(pressing escape, etc did not work):[Dell+Ubuntu Logo screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBfRx.jpg)

Using `nomodeset` again, I could get past this barrier and was able to click on "Try Ubuntu" again, however, the screen froze again in a minute after Ubuntu loaded. Tried this multiple times to get the same result. No key press worked. [Screen frozen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T2Sk.jpg)

Edit2: Note that it started freezing even with `nomodeset` only after using the update command mentioned above

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers and remove `nomodeset`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the post, can you check it? If that was not the right command to update, can you please share as to what is the right command?

Comment: Have the same problem and tried everything possible (terminal, gui and so on, all versions from official repo). Nvidia drivers don't work on my Dell Latitude 5491. If you activate them (don't really matter how console or gui) you really freeze OS booting. Only rescue mode from grub menu will help you. `nvidia-settings` also doesn't work, no dkms module  in `dkms-status` after installation (but some versions have it), no kernel module in `lsmod | grep nvidia`. Fortunatelly I have Intel card too.